# How to update the Mapview with new region from search result

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I would like for MapView to show or load new region, based on supplied data (latitude, longitude) after a user has searched a location from GoogleAutoComplete.

I'm using this airbnb package https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps

I tried `onRegionChange`, i dont find the right function to achieve this. here is my Mapview

```
 <MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
    style={style.map}
    region={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
     }}
    >
</MapView>
```

The map should move to or show that region after the user has clicked on the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a state with the initial region

```
state = { 
   region: {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
 }
}
```

Next, give it to the region attribute in your mapView and after searching update the region state

```
<MapView
provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
style={style.map}
region={this.state.region}
>
</MapView>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: My error was to only set the initialRegion, but not the region. The simple errors seem to really hit different.